# Trying to update substrings in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Can anyone help with some SQL syntax?

I have a table (TABLE A) which contains a 54 character field (FIELD A) which in essence contains 8x6 blocks of data.
These can be broken down into substrings:

- substr(FIELD A,1,6) as A
- substr(FIELD A,7,6) as B
- substr(FIELD A,13,6) as C
- substr(FIELD A,19,6) as D
- substr(FIELD A,25,6) as E
- substr(FIELD A,31,6) as F
- substr(FIELD A,37,6) as G
- substr(FIELD A,43,6) as H
- substr(FIELD A,49,6) as I

What I need to do is if there an occurrence of '404040' in any of these substring fields (A to I), replace them with '000000'. The '404040' has to be in these exact positions, not just a 'like %404040%' anywhere in FIELD A. I don't think I can perform an Update on a substring(?) but my efforts at using the Replace haven't yet worked. Can anyone suggest a solution?
I'm using SQL Developer 3.2.20.10 and Oracle 12.

Many Thanks AP

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: String manipulation functions vary considerably by database product. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: please post some sample data rows with expected results

Comment: _I don't think I can perform an Update on a substring_ Of-course you can. Use Oracle's other built-in, string manipulation functions. _but my efforts at using the Replace haven't yet worked_ Care to [edit] your question and post what you have tried?

Comment: FYI, https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using two functions `Replacepos` to replace the string at the position and `replacepos1` to mention the no_of_chars to be replaced.After that you can just use the below SQL

```
            WITH data
         AS (SELECT ROWNUM                       rw,
                    Lpad('404040', 54, '404040') A
             FROM   dual),
         d1
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 1, Replacepos1(a, '0', 1, 6)) A
             FROM   data),
         d2
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 7, Replacepos1(a, '0', 7, 6)) A
             FROM   d1),
         d3
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 13, Replacepos1(a, '0', 13, 6))A
             FROM   d2),
         d4
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 19, Replacepos1(a, '0', 19, 6))A
             FROM   d3),
         d5
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 25, Replacepos1(a, '0', 25, 6))A
             FROM   d4),
         d6
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 31, Replacepos1(a, '0', 31, 6))A
             FROM   d5),
         d7
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 37, Replacepos1(a, '0', 37, 6))A
             FROM   d6),
         d8
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 43, Replacepos1(a, '0', 43, 6))A
             FROM   d7),
         d9
         AS (SELECT rw,
                    Decode(Instr(a, '404040', 1), 49, Replacepos1(a, '0', 49, 6))A
             FROM   d8)
    SELECT A
    FROM   d9;
```

The Functions specifications below

```
   CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Replacepos(source_in      IN VARCHAR2,
                                          replacechar_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                          position_start IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      l_returnvalue VARCHAR2(32767);
      position_in   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        -- copy from the source string up to, but not including,  
        -- the character position  
        position_in := position_start;

        -- to be replaced  
        l_returnvalue := Substr(str1 => source_in, pos => 1, len => position_in - 1)
        ;

        -- add the replacement character  
        -- just a single character, but more can be sent in,  
        -- so substring the parameter  
        l_returnvalue := l_returnvalue
                         || Substr(str1 => replacechar_in, pos => 1, len => 1);

        -- copy the rest of the source string  
        l_returnvalue := l_returnvalue
                         || Substr(str1 => source_in, pos => position_in + 1);

        RETURN l_returnvalue;
    END replacepos;
```

AND the below function

```
    CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Replacepos1 (source_in      IN VARCHAR2,
                                            replacechar_in IN VARCHAR2,
                                            position_start IN NUMBER,
                                            no_of_chars    IN NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      l_returnvalue VARCHAR2(32767);
      position_in   NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        l_returnvalue := source_in;

        FOR i IN 1..no_of_chars LOOP
            l_returnvalue := Replacepos(l_returnvalue, replacechar_in,
                             position_start + i - 1);
        END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks psaraj12, much appreciated for your in-depth response.

Comment: You are welcome,if you got your solution please accept the answer